# I'm writing a fiction story about magic to distract me from porn, can it be justified?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, pornography, divine-justice

My story will include magic; I've read others that said it's fine to write any kind of fiction since it's considered expression of imagination, but I've also read that magic is not permissible in any way shape or form in Islam. Is it alright if I write characters with magical abilities?

I will not include religious aspects in my story, i.e. devils, pentagrams, etc. (unless you consider spirits to be religious). I will also refrain from having characters do things opposing Allah's teachings, i.e. zina, killing, etc.

I'm suffering from addiction of porn, and I'm writing to distract me from watching it. It has been a really great distraction method so far. But I don't know if it can be justified that I write about magic (which is, to my current knowledge, a possible sin) to distract me from porn and masturbation.

Answer (score 0):

Would reccomend writing about something else than magic if you really have to, some scholars say even fictional magic is haram